# Could not load schema information in BI PUBLISHER

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, bi-publisher

I deployed Oracle BI PUBLISHER 10G on Apache Tomcat
and in the data source, i add MySQL data source and test it( I added MySQL 5.1.9 driver to lib of the Apache Tomcat). every thing is good and the connection test was successful, but when I'm in the data model and want to **create data set** click on ***QUERY BUILDER*** I face with error :

***Could not load schema information. Please make sure that this connection is active.***

Every connection test is OK .
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question ! :D .

This is just a bug when you are using Oracle Bi Publisher 10g  with MySQL driver . 
I tested Connection with Oracle Bi Publisher 12c and it works perfectly .